# How to send SQL query from C# with backslashes?

Tags: c#, sql, escaping

I want to execute a SQL query from my C# project. My problem is that I use in the query the connection string, which includes `\`. I have to escape it but the SQL can't get `\\`. I tried use `@`, but it still didn't work.

My SQL Query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO [SQL_TABLE] 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source 
            =Y:\\MyAccess\\MyDB\\myAccessFile.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = 
            1234;].[ACCESS_TABLE] 
    WHERE [ID] = 1234
```

The SQL get it with `\\`, but accept `\`.

I have tried even:

```
for(int i = 0;i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   try
   {
       string selectSQL = "SELECT * 
                           FROM [" + @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
                              Data Source 
                              =Y:\MyAccess\MyDB\myAccessFile.md; Jet 
                              OLEDB:Database Password = 1234;]. 
                              [VTblASMCustomersDocumentsAndGroupCodes] 
                           WHERE [ID] = 1234"
       string sql = "INSERT INTO [SQL_TABLE] " + selectSQL;
       executeSQLQuery(sql, connectionStringSQL);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
 }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth tagging this with ms-access? Seems to be specific to that non-standard dialect of SQL.

Comment: @JGFMK. It use SQL DB in the `INSERT`, and ACCESS DB in the `SELECT`.

Comment: It should work either with \\ (first \ escapes second \) or with `@`, which makes \ not reuqire to be escaped. You surely have problem somewhere else.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn. Thanks. My problem is that in the C# it requires 2 slashes, but the SQL - just one, and it gets the escape slash as 2  slashes. My second problem is that I get the path with the slashes as aparameter, so how do I use `@`?

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
var query = @"INSERT INTO [SQL_TABLE] 
            SELECT * 
            FROM [Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source 
                    =Y:\MyAccess\MyDB\myAccessFile.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = 
                    1234;].[ACCESS_TABLE] 
            WHERE [ID] = 1234"
```

Refer to [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8):

> literal backslashes in a string must be escaped or the entire string must be @-quoted.

Above means that if you use `@` before the string you don't need to escape `\` and it's treated as it is.

Comment: But the C# doesn't accept it. It required `Y:\\MyAccess\\MyDB\\myAccessFile.mdb`

Comment: @utor, c# "accept", notice `@` prefix on string value. This will tell c# to accept string as it is.

Comment: @utor, can you display how you are sending query to the sql server?

Comment: @utor How do you know it? Did you try executing the code?

Comment: @Fabio and Michał Turczyn, I edited my question and added my C# code. Thank you!

Comment: "But the SQL get it anyway as \\" no, it does not. You are getting fooled with Visual Studio watch window, even when you have only \ in a string it shows you \\. If you @"\" the string has only one backslash, pretty much the same as if you did "\\" without the @ literal. Visual Studio watch windows will show in both cases \\.

Answer (score 1):

check[escape character](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/) its need \ \ to have '\' as the '\' considered escape character.

however i suggested for you to use the [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) for multi connection with sql server